# Empty ModelFormset in Django's FormWizard

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm using Django's FormWizard. It works fine but I'm having trouble getting any empty model formset to display correctly.

I have a model called `Domain`. I'm creating a ModelFormset like this:

```
DomainFormset = modelformset_factory(Domain)
```

I pass this to the FormWizard like this:

```
BuyNowWizardView.as_view([DomainFormset])
```

I don't get any errors but when the wizard renders the page, I get a list of all `Domain` objects. I'd like to get an empty form. How I can do this? I've read that I can give a `queryset` parameter to the ModelFormset like `Domain.objects.none()` but it doesn't seem to work as I get errors.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what errors do you get when setting the queryset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Django docs give two ways to [change the queryset for a formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset).

The first way is to pass the queryset as an argument when instantiating the formset. With the formwizard, you can do this by passing [`instance_dict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.instance_dict)

```
# set the queryset for step '0' of the formset
instance_dict = {'0': Domain.objects.none()}

# in your url patterns
url(r'^$', BuyNowWizardView.as_view([UserFormSet], instance_dict=instance_dict)),
```

The second approach is to subclass `BaseModelFormSet` and override the `__init__` method to use the empty queryset.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseModelFormSet

class BaseDomainFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseDomainFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Domain.objects.none()

DomainFormSet = modelformset_factory(Domain, formset=BaseDomainFormSet)
```

You then pass `DomainFormSet` to the form wizard as before.

Comment: Hey Alasdair, I've tried the method you mentioned and I still get form fields with the data filled in. I'm wondering if this is a bug. The only difference from the regular form wizard that I'm using the newer one from Django 1.4 which has been backported to DJango 1.3 https://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard

Comment: What do you mean by *filled in*? Is it displaying existing domains from the database, or just pre-filling the forms with `initial` data?

Comment: Yes, it is displaying all the existing domains from the database.  I get one form for each `Domain` record with the values in it.

Comment: Hmm. I made a test project (Django trunk, 1.4 pre-alpha), and the subclassing method does not work for me either. I have updated my answer with the `instance_dict` approach, which **does** work for me.