# Using ModelFormset with Form Wizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset, django-formwizard

I have this section in my models.py:

```
class AdrecaProjecteAutoocupat(Adreca):

[...]

designacio = models.CharField(
    max_length=128, verbose_name=u"designació",
    help_text=u"nom per identificar aquesta adreça, \
        especialment si n'hi ha més d'una \
        al projecte; p.ex. es podrien dir \"restaurant\" i \"botiga\".")

traspas = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, choices=TIPUS_TRASPAS, default=TIPUS_TRASPAS_CAP)
traspas_comentaris_avaluacio = models.TextField(
    max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True,
    help_text=u"Comentaris que es fan als membres de referència en el \
        moment de demanar-los la cessió")
traspas_inici = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
traspas_final = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
traspas_comentaris_alta = models.TextField(
    max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True,
    help_text=u"Observacions i particularitats recollides durant l'alta")

traspas_lloguer_import_mensual = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=8, decimal_places=2,
    blank=True, null=True,
    verbose_name=u"import mensual del lloguer")

activitats = models.ManyToManyField(
    Activitat,
    blank=True, null=True,
    limit_choices_to={'firaire': False})

class Meta:
    verbose_name = u"adreça de projecte autoocupat"
    verbose_name_plural = u"adreces de projectes autoocupats"
```

That i use in my forms.py to generate a ModelFormSet:

```
class FormulariAdrecaProjecteAutoocupat(forms.ModelForm):
"""
Step 4
"""
projecte = None

class Meta:
    model = AdrecaProjecteAutoocupat
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'traspas': forms.RadioSelect(),
        'activitats': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    }


class EmptyAdrecesFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmptyAdrecesFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = AdrecaProjecteAutoocupat.objects.none()


AdrecesFormSet = modelformset_factory(AdrecaProjecteAutoocupat,
                                  formset=EmptyAdrecesFormSet,
                                  form=FormulariAdrecaProjecteAutoocupat,
                                  extra=0,
                                  min_num=1,
                                  can_delete=True)
```

Then i pass it in my urls.py to a NamedUrlSessionFormWizard...

The problem that i'm facing is the following:

i try to use modelformset to render empty forms. the point about it is that i don't know how many instances of the model the user wants so i thought about using model formsets and set up a minimum of one that is what is required for the general form.

When i set up the minimum of 1 and the queryset to none, it seems to not have nothing to show so it throw an error about the minimum. but if use default queryset, it shows me already existing instances as if i wanted to edit them.

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316145/empty-modelformset-in-djangos-formwizard) but is not helping me too much.

so one of my questions could be:
Is there a way to use modelformset for create new instances of a model?

another could be:
Is it that i'm not focusing the right error, and this can be solved somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Did you tired to set `extra` value and removing `min_num`?

Comment: yes i tried but i still get a key error with value 0. that i interpret as it is looking for an instance that it doesn't exist

Comment: i just deleted old instances... and trying again but same error is raised

Comment: if i set extra=0 and no min_num instead i got a rendered template with any form

Comment: s/"with any form"/"with no form"/*